# nginx - preserve bookmarks on domain move

Tags: redirect, nginx, web, bookmarks

We're moving a website from `www.xdomain.com` to `www.ydomain.com`

It's primarily a forum, with many topics.

Therefore it would be common for someone to bookmark e.g.

`www.xdomain.com/forum/board/topic?blah` or something.

Our goal is to have a seamless transfer from one domain to the other (currently we have both domains pointing to the same folder in hosting), but we would prefer this to happen:

`www.xdomain.com/forum/board/topic?blah` redirects to `www.ydomain.com/forum/board/topic?blah`

i.e. the ONLY changes is BEFORE the .com - all the subfolders are exactly the same and compatiable.

Is this possible to do? If so, how could I do it in nginx?
The main reason is for bookmarks AND to force the use of our new domain.

Thanks.

Comment: It's important to note that you must keep `xdomain.com` registered and pointing to your server for any sort of  nginx-based redirection to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use two `server` blocks, one for each domain. Then set a permanent redirect.

```
server {
    server_name www.xdomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.ydomain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name www.ydomain.com;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.